# APA: How to cite chapter and edition in book

Tags: citations, citation-style

I was wondering the correct format for citing when including both book edition and the page range of the chapter.

From owl purdue on citing chapter (APA):

> Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (Year of publication). Title of
>   chapter. In A. A. Editor & B. B. Editor (Eds.), *Title of book* (pages
>   of chapter). Location: Publisher.

Would the correct format then look like this?

> Author, A. A., & Author, B. B. (Year of publication). Title of
>   chapter. In A. A. Editor & B. B. Editor (Eds.), *Title of book*
>   (**Edition, pages of chapter**). Location: Publisher.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (I know at least of [one journal](http://www.management-revue.org/authors_guidelines.php), giving such recommendations in addition to the APA style).
But in this form, according to my experience, it's more common for the MLA style while rarely used with the APA. What you also might want to do is to include two references: one for the chapter (only pages in parentheses) and another for the edited book (only edition in parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be the correct format. Though I couldn't find any guidance from APA, I did find a citation in that format in Educational Evaluation and Policy Analysis, a journal that uses APA.

Here's the citation:

Bronfenbrenner, U., & Morris, P.A. (1998). The ecology of developmental processes. In W. Damon & R.M. Lerner (Ed.), *Handbook of Child Psychology: Vol 1. Theoretical models of human development* (5th ed., pp.993-1028). Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley.

This citation appears Volume 38, No. 4, p. 778.